# Modifying the grammar to include another operator

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I have this grammar for arithmetic expressions

E -> E+T | T

T -> T X F | F     (X is cross product operator)

F -> (E) | a

Now I am  wanting to add the exponential operator ^ to it, it needs to have higher precedence than multiplication and it needs to be right associative.

Would this be correct? Since first we write the steps for lower precedence?

E -> E+T | T

T -> T*F | F   (multiplication)

F -> F^X| B    **or is it X -> F^X to make it right associative?**

B -> (E) | a

F -> (E) | a